# Will the browser download the DOCTYPE .dtd file?

Tags: html, xml, browser, doctype, dtd

I know that the DOCTYPE(s) give the browser the list of allowed elements(tags) and attributes.

But i want to know that when you use:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Will the browser go and download the dtd file or it just a sign that the browsers understand that the type of the HTML is HTML 4(strict).

What about HTML 5 DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Thank You.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration ...

Comment: I'm sorry but it's too long,Would you please tell me important parts as an answer?

Comment: I would but then it would be too short for me, I like giving long information only.

Comment: I'm MUCH confused,What is the relation of HTML and XML,Why XML does not allow tags closing tag missing but HTML allows it? What exactly the DOCTYPE says ? Can it also say that this HTML document can ignore missing of closing tags? What about xmlns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not download DTD files. There is no prohibition, but they just don’t use DTDs at all, and they are not required at all. The `doctype` declarations matter only as “magic strings”, which trigger standards, almost standars, or quirks mode in the browser; this is based solely on the string as such, without accessing any DTD file.

The `doctype` declarations are a holdover from the time when HTML was defined nominally as an application of SGML – something that was never implemented. An SGML processor is allowed to read a DTD and perform validation against it; it will then be called a validating SGML processor. But browsers never did that. Instead, HTML authors may use separate validators (which only validate, without displaying the document at all).

The `doctype` declarations have been kept because browser vendors once decided to use the presence or absence of such declarations, and their exact form (as strings), when deciding whether the document should be rendered in “standards mode” or “quirks mode”. HTML5 follows this tradition, although in HTML5, it’s not even nominally a declaration of any kind, just a “`doctype` string”.